# Undeclared Identifier while creating a root signature

Tags: c++, directx-12

How do I compile a "standalone" root signature for use with D3D12 pipeline state objects?

I've been following the steps outlined on this [MSDN page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/direct3d12/specifying-root-signatures-in-hlsl) to try to compile a D3D12 Root Signature from hlsl but so far I must have missed a crucial detail because they all yield the same error:

`error X3004: undeclared identifier 'ALLOW_INPUT_ASSEMBLER_INPUT_LAYOUT'`

Method A:

```
#include <d3dcompiler.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <wrl.h>

const char* definition =
    "#define RS1 "
    "RootFlags(ALLOW_INPUT_ASSEMBLER_INPUT_LAYOUT | DENY_HULL_SHADER_ROOT_ACCESS | DENY_DOMAIN_SHADER_ROOT_ACCESS | DENY_GEOMETRY_SHADER_ROOT_ACCESS),"
    "DescriptorTable(SRV(t0, flags = DATA_STATIC), visibility = SHADER_VISIBILITY_PIXEL),"
    "DescriptorTable(CBV(b0, flags = DATA_STATIC), visibility = SHADER_VISIBILITY_VERTEX),"
    "StaticSampler(s0, addressU = TEXTURE_ADDRESS_BORDER, filter = FILTER_MIN_MAG_MIP_POINT)";

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE /*hInstance*/, HINSTANCE, LPSTR, int /*nCmdShow*/)
{
    {
        Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3DBlob> errorMsgs;
        Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3DBlob> signatureBlob;
        if (FAILED(D3DCompile(definition, strlen(definition), nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, "RS1", "rootsig_1_1", 0, 0, &signatureBlob, &errorMsgs)))
        {
            OutputDebugStringA((LPCSTR)errorMsgs.Get()->GetBufferPointer());
        }
    }

    {
        Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3DBlob> errorMsgs;
        Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3DBlob> signatureBlob;
        if (FAILED(D3DCompile2(definition, strlen(definition), nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, "RS1", "rootsig_1_1", 0, D3DCOMPILE_FLAGS2_FORCE_ROOT_SIGNATURE_1_1, 0, nullptr, 0, &signatureBlob, &errorMsgs)))
        {
            OutputDebugStringA((LPCSTR)errorMsgs.Get()->GetBufferPointer());
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Method B:

A file called fxc_rootsig_test.hlsl, containing:

```
#define RS1 RootFlags(ALLOW_INPUT_ASSEMBLER_INPUT_LAYOUT | DENY_HULL_SHADER_ROOT_ACCESS | DENY_DOMAIN_SHADER_ROOT_ACCESS | DENY_GEOMETRY_SHADER_ROOT_ACCESS), \
            DescriptorTable(SRV(t0, flags = DATA_STATIC), visibility = SHADER_VISIBILITY_PIXEL), \
            DescriptorTable(CBV(b0, flags = DATA_STATIC), visibility = SHADER_VISIBILITY_VERTEX), \
            StaticSampler(s0, addressU = TEXTURE_ADDRESS_BORDER, addressV = TEXTURE_ADDRESS_BORDER, filter = FILTER_MIN_MAG_MIP_POINT)
```

and invoking fxc with the following command line: `fxc.exe /T rootsig_1_1 fxc_rootsig_test.hlsl /E RS1 /Fo fxc_rootsig_test.fxo`

Other relevant information:

- Platform: Windows 10 x64 (Version 1803)
- Windows SDK Version: 10.0.17763.0
- Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition (15.9.3)

P.S: I've also tried several variations on the string in the file, with `[RootSignature(RS1)]` and also with a shader and then trying to compile with the target for that shader i.e. `ps_5_1`.

P.P.S: I've also tried removing `ALLOW_INPUT_ASSEMBLER_INPUT_LAYOUT` but then it just complains about `DENY_HULL_SHADER_ROOT_ACCESS` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add some more quotes. A root signature needs to be a quoted string:

```
#define RS1 "RootFlags(ALLOW_INPUT_ASSEMBLER_INPUT_LAYOUT | DENY_HULL_SHADER_ROOT_ACCESS | DENY_DOMAIN_SHADER_ROOT_ACCESS | DENY_GEOMETRY_SHADER_ROOT_ACCESS), " \
"            DescriptorTable(SRV(t0, flags = DATA_STATIC), visibility = SHADER_VISIBILITY_PIXEL)," \
"            DescriptorTable(CBV(b0, flags = DATA_STATIC), visibility = SHADER_VISIBILITY_VERTEX)," \
"            StaticSampler(s0, addressU = TEXTURE_ADDRESS_BORDER, addressV = TEXTURE_ADDRESS_BORDER, filter = FILTER_MIN_MAG_MIP_POINT)"
```

Comment: I feel so silly for missing such a simple detail. Thanks!

Comment: You'll note that most official DirectX 12 samples for PC/UWP just use code-built root signatures and don't bother with HLSL-based ones. The HLSL-based root signatures are a necessary evil for Xbox One development due to the load-time performance of "fully precompiled" shaders, but generally when working with [DirectX Tool Kit for DX12](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK12) I've found them to be a [PITA](https://www.allacronyms.com/PITA/Pain_in_the_Ass).

Comment: Alright, I will stick with code based version. Thank you for the advice :)